# Background Gradient with Magick++

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, magick++

How do I create gradients with ImageMagick in C++?

I am trying to create a visual representation of a WAV file.

I can create an Image with Magick++, draw in the waveform data and save the image as a .png file but it still looks a bit basic.

I'd like to give the image background and waveform gradients but I don't know how.

Are there any examples of how to create gradients using Magick++?

Many thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would have to use the Pixel class and interpolate Colors to create your own gradient fill.

The [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/tutorial/Magick++_tutorial.pdf) for Magick++ does not indicate that it has native functions for gradient fill.

It may also be possible to use the [core ImageMagick API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php) for gradient fill.

Here's some useful links:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/
- http://softwareas.com/imagemagick-one-second-gradient-images

**Edit** - The Magick Core API does have a [DrawGradientImage](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/draw.php) function which may help you out.

Here's some more useful links:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/struct__GradientInfo.html
- http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/index.html
- http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/draw_8c_source.html#l03225

Comment: Ok, I was hoping someone would show me a fillGradient() function but I guess it wouldn't be too hard to loop though a matrix and set the colour of each pixel. I probably need to continue reading the manual.
Thanks anyway.